# what does '%%' do in multiline strings?

Tags: python, string, bottle

I was messing around with the modules in my `site-packages` folder when I found a Python file: `bottle.py`.

From what I can read, it is used for small web applications.
I was curious to read its source so I got into it.

However, in the last part of the script (lines: 3720-3753) they made a strange use of the Python's multiline string...
Here's the code:

```py
ERROR_PAGE_TEMPLATE = """
%%try:
    %%from %s import DEBUG, HTTP_CODES, request, touni
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Error: {{e.status}}</title>
            <style type="text/css">
              html {background-color: #eee; font-family: sans;}
              body {background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #ddd;
                    padding: 15px; margin: 15px;}
              pre {background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Error: {{e.status}}</h1>
            <p>Sorry, the requested URL <tt>{{repr(request.url)}}</tt>
               caused an error:</p>
            <pre>{{e.body}}</pre>
            %%if DEBUG and e.exception:
              <h2>Exception:</h2>
              <pre>{{repr(e.exception)}}</pre>
            %%end
            %%if DEBUG and e.traceback:
              <h2>Traceback:</h2>
              <pre>{{e.traceback}}</pre>
            %%end
        </body>
    </html>
%%except ImportError:
    <b>ImportError:</b> Could not generate the error page. Please add bottle to
    the import path.
%%end
""" % __name__
```

What does the `%%` operator do exactly?
I tried to search for it on Google but I couldn't find much.

Also, what are its other uses?

PS: the `{{variable}}` expressions are possible in every multiline script in Python?

Comment: This has nothing to do with bottle. You're using the `%` operator to format the string. `%%` is used to generate literal `%` in the result, since `%` is replaced with the parameter to `%`.

Comment: The `{{abc}}` syntax is part of the bottle templating system.  That's how they do substitution.  It's similar to the `f"{abc}"` notation in modern Python's f-strings.

Comment: so that's like another "marker" that they replace in the compile phase, I understood, thank u!

Comment: To be more specific, `"%%"` and `"{{xxx}}`" mean nothing in a multi-ling string.  It's just a string.  `"%%"` means something to the `%` operator, and `{{xxx}}` means something to bottle.

Comment: alright, everything's more clear now, thank you so much! However... now should I leave the post as it is or delete it because it's closed? I never know what to do in this cases

Answer (score 0):

It acts as an escape character:

```py
>>> x = 'abc'
>>> '%s' % x
'abc'
>>> '%s %%' % x
'abc %'
```

Comment: oh, now I understand... so that isn't an "operator", it's just a marker that they needed to process those lines of code by themselves, right?